# Overfitting cross-validation scores

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting

I've ran 1000 iterations of XGBClassifier parameters search using RandomizedSearchCV on the titanic dataset. That's just for context, but the question applies to any CV search method, any model and any dataset.

I consistently see that the best CV accuracy scores are achieved on models that are overfitting on the training set, while models that have similar performance in both train and test scores never reach the same level of CV scores (dots marked in orange).

I fail to understand what causes this phenomena? 
I mean - I understand overfitting, but don't understand why there are no models that have the same CV score as the best ones, but which don't overfit the train set. I would expect there to be dots where the dashed green line intersects the orange line.
What causes this?

And beyond that, when evaluating the performance on a holdout set, the models with the best CV scores, score lower then the best models that had similar test and train scores (the highest of the orange dots).
Why doesn't maximising the CV scores produce the best generalisation? Should my go-to strategy be maximising CV scores that don't show signs of overfitting (orange dots)?

[image]

Comment: What kind of scores are those? For each fold of each CV? Or already averaged? And where is what you call "CV accuracy score" for each of those points?

Comment: @Denwid the scores are averaged on the folds. The "CV accuracy score" is the y-axis, aka "mean_test_score"